# Wrong string representation of floating point value

Tags: php, factorial, floating-point-conversion

I'm using this function for calculating factorial:

```
function factorial($in) {
    // 0! = 1! = 1
    $out = 1;

    // Only if $in is >= 2
    for ($i = 2; $i <= $in; $i++) {
        $out *= $i;
    }

    return $out;
}
```

And trying to convert float value to some kind of bigint string representation. But starting from 23! the result value is incorrect. The output is:

```
2.5852016738885E+22 <- this is the result (float)
25852016738884978212864 <- incorrect
25852016738884978212864 <- incorrect
25852016738884976640000 <- correct (used GMP library for calculation)
```

The script itself:

```
<?php

//starting from 23 the result becomes incorrect if convert it to "integer string"
define('F_NUMBER', 23);

function factorial($in) {
    // 0! = 1! = 1
    $out = 1;

    // Only if $in is >= 2
    for ($i = 2; $i <= $in; $i++) {
        $out *= $i;
    }

    return $out;
}


$f = factorial(F_NUMBER);
echo "$f" . PHP_EOL; //The result as float
echo number_format($f, 0, '', '') . PHP_EOL; //Incorrect result
printf("%.0f" . PHP_EOL, $f); //Incorrect result
echo gmp_strval(gmp_fact(F_NUMBER)) . PHP_EOL; //Correct result
```

Why is that happening? How can this problem be solved without GMP library?

Comment: `25852016738884978212864` is too large for PHP to store it in a 32bit int, [so it stores it as a float](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.integer.php#language.types.integer.overflow) which is subject to the hellish nightmare of floating point precision, I don't know how you would go about fixing or even mitigating this but that's my theory.